# Authentication Process is not triggered when using IBM App ID in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress, ibm-appid

I'm trying to use this feature: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-kube-auth#kube-auth

I've followed the steps in the documentation, but the authentication process is not triggered. Unfortunately I don't see any errors and don't know what else to do.

Here is my sample service (nginx.yaml):

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: NodePort
```

Here is my sample service (ingress.yaml). Replace 'niklas-heidloff-4' with your cluster name and 'niklas-heidloff-appid' with the name of your App ID service instance.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-app-id
  annotations:   
    ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth: "bindSecret=binding-niklas-heidloff-appid namespace=default requestType=web"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - niklas.niklas-heidloff-4.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
    secretName: niklas-heidloff-4
  rules:
  - host: niklas.niklas-heidloff-4.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

Here are the steps to reproduce the sample:

First create a new cluster with at least two worker nodes in Dallas as described in the documentation. Note that it can take some extra time to get a public IP for your cluster.

Then create a App ID service instance.

Then invoke the following commands (replace 'niklas-heidloff-4' with your cluster name):

```
$ ibmcloud login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
$ ibmcloud ks region-set us-south
$ ibmcloud ks cluster-config niklas-heidloff-4 (and execute export....)
$ ibmcloud ks cluster-service-bind --cluster niklas-heidloff-4 --namespace default --service niklas-heidloff-appid
$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml
```

After this I could open 'https://niklas.niklas-heidloff-4.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/' but the authentication process is not triggered and the page opens without authentication.

Comment: The only difference I see to this tutorial is that the service name is included for the ingress auth: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/secure-file-storage.template.yaml

Comment: Thanks Henrik. I tried it with the service name as well but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the steps mentioned in the [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-kube-auth#kube-auth) and this is how it **worked** for me.

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  annotations:
    ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth: "bindSecret=binding-appid-ks namespace=default requestType=web serviceName=nginx idToken=false"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - test.vidya-think-cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
      secretName: vidya-think-cluster
  rules:
    - host: test.vidya-think-cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: nginx
              servicePort: 80
```

I added the following web redirect URL in the `authentication settings` of App ID service - `http://test.vidya-think-cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/appid_callback`.

Now, when you try accessing the app at `http://test.vidya-think-cluster.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/` you should see the redirection to App ID

Looks like `idToken=false` is a mandatory parameter as there is an error when you run `kubectl describe myingress`

**Error**:  *Failed to apply ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth annotation. Error annotation format error : One of the mandatory fields not valid/missing for annotation ingress.bluemix.net/appid-auth*